# Which modules have exactly one maximal submodule?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R, {\frak m})$ be a Noetherian local ring. When a finitely generated module has exactly one maximal submodule?

Comment: Only modules of the form $R/I$ for an ideal $I$.

Comment: Thanks. How can we prove it?

Comment: If $N$ is such a maximal submodule of $M$, then $M/N$ can not have a non-trivial submodule, so it must be $R/\mathfrak{m}$. In particular, $N$ must contain $\mathfrak{m}M$ and use Nakayama's lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M \neq 0$ has exactly one maximal submodule, the same holds for $M/\mathfrak mM$. This is a $R/\mathfrak m$-vector space. Clearly a vector space with exactly one maximal subspace must be one-dimensional. By Nakayama, $M$ is cyclic, i.e. isomorphic to $R/\operatorname{Ann}(M)$.